# Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact: Where's the Mailing Address?

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, contacts

Where in the Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact would I find the property that relates to the Outlook.ContactItem.SelectedMailingAddress?

Outlook has the Outlook.ContactItem.SelectedMailingAddress property, which holds an Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMailingAddress enum:

```
_currentContact.SelectedMailingAddress = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMailingAddress.olBusiness;
```

Outlook also populates a full set of Address properties:

```
_currentContact.MailingAddress = _currentContact.BusinessAddress;
_currentContact.MailingAddressCity = _currentContact.BusinessAddressCity;
_currentContact.MailingAddressCountry = _currentContact.BusinessAddressCountry;
_currentContact.MailingAddressPostalCode = _currentContact.BusinessAddressPostalCode;
_currentContact.MailingAddressState = _currentContact.BusinessAddressState;
_currentContact.MailingAddressStreet = _currentContact.BusinessAddressStreet;
```

But I can find nothing in EWS for Mailing Address. The Exchange.WebServices.Data.PhysicalAddressKey enum only contains Business, Home, and Other.

I'm pulling my hair out here!  Any help or direction would be truly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked the [ProxyAdress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563519(v=exchg.80).aspx) as explained here?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this Bastian! Could the ProxyAddress possibly affect a single property of the EWS Contact object?  I am able to retrieve and update Contacts via EWS with no problem.  My problem is setting which Address (Business, Home, Other) is the Mailing Address.  Presumably that is a single property (Perhaps an Extended Property?) of the Contact Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PidLidPostalAddressId https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee179151(v=exchg.80).aspx property specifies which of the addresses are used as the Postal address. In EWS you need to set it (or get that value) using an extended property eg

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidPostalAddressId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x8022, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
Contact.SetExtendedProperty(PidLidPostalAddressId, 0x00000002);
```

Would set the Mailing address to the Business Address

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will try it out first thing tomorrow.  I had a feeling it was an extended property.  I Googled everything I could think of for hours.  Again, thanks for taking the time to share some of your knowledge with me.